# manually start a view controller using storyboards.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to manually start a view controller using storyboards.

That is written in code as opposed to wiring it up. I tried:

```
self initWithNibName:(NSString *) bundle:(NSBundle *)
```

but I am not sure if they are classed as nibs or what they are classed as in storyboards. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for this method:

```
AlertContainerViewController *alertContainerViewController = 
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:NULL] 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alertContainer"];
```

You need to give the ViewController object in the Storyboard a unique identifier and specify the subclass. You do both through the Property Inspector.

Comment: Why `bundle:NULL` instead of `bundle:nil`?